# Why is my domain to dto converter called twice?

Tags: wcf, ienumerable

I encounted a strange behavior in my wcf service. This is my opreation contract implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<Dto.ProductType> GetAllProductTypes()
{
    return m_InventoryRepository.GetAllProductTypes().Select(DomainToDtoConverter.ConvertToDto);
}
```

If I have let say 3000 product types, then I should expect that my domain to dto converter is called 3000 times. But this is not the case; it is called 6000 times. If I then ensure that I load all the items before I return like this:

```
...Select(DomainToDtoConverter.ConvertToDto).ToList();
```

...then the converter is called the 3000 times that I would expect.

Anyone know why this happens?

I guess we will change all our operation contracts to return an array instead of IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

LINQ methods use lazy evaluation; the method runs again each time you iterate the results.

Calling `ToList()` forces it to create a collection containing all of the results, allowing you to iterate that collection without re-executing anything.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't understand why wcf resolve my IEnumerable twice. What happens behind the scene?

Comment: It's _iterating_ the sequence twice.  You can put a breakpoint in the method and look at the callstack to find out where.